# Running angular-material with jspm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, jspm, systemjs

I've the problem to load angular-material, which I've installed with jspm.  by Systemjs.

I'm allways reciving:

> uncaught exception: Not Found:
>   http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/github/angular/bower-material@0.10.0/angular-material

this is my Systemjs configuration, created by jspm

```
System.config({
  "baseURL": "/",
  "transpiler": "traceur",
  "paths": {
    "*": "*.js",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*.js"
  }
});

System.config({
  "map": {
    "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.3",
    "angular-animate": "github:angular/bower-angular-animate@1.4.3",
    "angular-aria": "github:angular/bower-angular-aria@1.4.3",
    "angular-material": "github:angular/bower-material@0.10.0",
    "traceur": "github:jmcriffey/bower-traceur@0.0.88",
    "traceur-runtime": "github:jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.88",
    "github:angular/bower-angular-animate@1.4.3": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.3"
    },
    "github:angular/bower-angular-aria@1.4.3": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.3"
    },
    "github:angular/bower-material@0.10.0": {
      "angular": "github:angular/bower-angular@1.4.3",
      "angular-animate": "github:angular/bower-angular-animate@1.4.3",
      "angular-aria": "github:angular/bower-angular-aria@1.4.3",
      "css": "github:systemjs/plugin-css@0.1.13"
    }
  }
});
```

This is my Mainjs:

```
var angular = require("angular");
require("angular-material");
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ["ngMaterial"]);
```

which I'm loading in my index.html:

```
<script>
    System.import("Main");
</script>
```

Whats wrong about this

Comment: Hi! My config looks exactly like yours, except for 2 things. I eliminated the `baseUrl` and I'm using [babel](https://babeljs.io/) instead of traceur. If you think it would help, I can post my configuration here.

Answer (score 0):

Must be a bug in your config. Here is the procedure so far (2016/02) with example taken from [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/content)

First :
`jspm install angular angular-animate angular-aria angular-material`

```js
window.define = System.amdDefine;
window.require = window.requirejs = System.amdRequire;

require([
  'angular',
  'angular-aria',
  'angular-animate',
  'angular-material',
  'angular-material/angular-material.css!',
  'angular-material/angular-material.layouts.css!'
], function(angular) {
  var app = angular.module('App', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate', 'ngAria']);

  app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.title = document.title;
    }
  ]);

  // angular manual initialisation since we use a script loader
  // cf. http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('Bootstrapping angular...');
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['App'], {
      strictDi: true
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Angular Material</title>
  <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<div class="contentdemoBasicUsage" ng-controller="AppCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="">
  <md-toolbar class="md-warn">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <h2 class="md-flex">{{title}}</h2>
    </div>
  </md-toolbar>

  <md-content flex="" layout-padding="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne quod novum mei. Sea omnium invenire mediocrem at, in lobortis conclusionemque nam. Ne deleniti appetere reprimique pro, inani labitur disputationi te sed. At vix sale omnesque, id pro labitur reformidans accommodare,
      cum labores honestatis eu. Nec quem lucilius in, eam praesent reformidans no. Sed laudem aliquam ne.</p>

    <p>
      Facete delenit argumentum cum at. Pro rebum nostrum contentiones ad. Mel exerci tritani maiorum at, mea te audire phaedrum, mel et nibh aliquam. Malis causae equidem vel eu. Noster melius vis ea, duis alterum oporteat ea sea. Per cu vide munere fierent.
    </p>
  </md-content>
</div>
```